# Вытащить пять первых предложений из текста

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на PHP вытащить пять первых предложений из нижеприведенного текста?

> Cicero famously orated against his! Political opponent Lucius Sergius Catilina. Погода сегодня хорошая!
>
> Occasionally the first Oration against Catiline is taken for type specimens: quo usque tandem abutere, Catilina, patientia nostra? Quam diu etiam furor iste tuus nos eludet? Cicero writing letters. Or maybe not.

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [strpbrk()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpbrk.php), которая ищет любой символ из набора. В набор включить все символы, которые могут являться окончанием строки. И далее в цикле `while()` попробовать найти эти символы в тексте. Если один из символов найден, вырезать подстроку от начала текста до найденной позиции с ее захватом. Это будет одно предложение. Далее повторить еще 4 раза.

Comment: А что если мы не знаем, что там и какие символы, может текст приходит откуда-то, или записывается кем-то.

Answer (score 2):

**Первый вариант:**

```
$STRING = 'Cicero famously orated against his! Political opponent Lucius Sergius Catilina. Погода сегодня хорошая!

Occasionally the first Oration against Catiline is taken for type specimens: quo usque tandem abutere, Catilina, patientia nostra? Quam diu etiam furor iste tuus nos eludet? Cicero writing letters. Or maybe not.';

// Обрезаем массив
$EXP = array_map('trim', preg_split("/(\.|!|\?)/", $STRING, 6, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
if (count($EXP) % 2 != 0) {
    array_pop($EXP);
}

// Создаем результирующий
$RESULT = array();
foreach ($EXP as $key => $value)
{
    if ($key % 2 == 0)
    {
        $RESULT[] = $value . $EXP[$key + 1];
    }
}
var_dump($RESULT);
```

**Второй вариант (*моя реализация того, что уже предложили ранее*):**

```
$STRING = 'Cicero famously orated against his! Political opponent Lucius Sergius Catilina. Погода сегодня хорошая!

Occasionally the first Oration against Catiline is taken for type specimens: quo usque tandem abutere, Catilina, patientia nostra? Quam diu etiam furor iste tuus nos eludet? Cicero writing letters. Or maybe not.';

// Обрабатываем
$SEPARATOR_REPLACE_1 = array(PHP_EOL, '.', '!', '?');
$SEPARATOR_REPLACE_2 = array('', '.' . PHP_EOL, '!' . PHP_EOL, '?' . PHP_EOL);
$EXP  = array_diff(array_map('trim', explode(PHP_EOL, str_replace($SEPARATOR_REPLACE_1, $SEPARATOR_REPLACE_2, $STRING))), array(''));
// Результат
$RESULT = array_slice($EXP, 0, 5);
var_dump($RESULT);
```

Выбирайте сами, предложенные варианты можно еще и упростить, но писалось чтобы вы поняли суть.

P.S. Данные примеры не претендуют на самое оптимальное решение.

Answer (score 1):

```html
$text = 'Cicero famously orated against his! Political opponent Lucius Sergius Catilina. Погода сегодня хорошая! Occasionally the first Oration against Catiline is taken for type specimens: quo usque tandem abutere, Catilina, patientia nostra? Quam diu etiam furor iste tuus nos eludet? Cicero writing letters. Or maybe not.';

//Так как символ окончания сткроки есть ".", "!" и "?" идентифицыруем  концы строки.

$text = str_replace(". ", ". ~", $text);
$text = str_replace("! ", "! ~", $text);
$text = str_replace("? ", "? ~", $text);

//Теперь символ "~" указывает на то что после него начинается новая строка. Разбиваем строку на подстроки

$text_line_array = explode("~", $text);

//Выводим первые 4 строки

for($i=0; $i=4; $i++){
    echo $text_line_array[$i];
}
```

Comment: Работать этот код не будет, тем более написан не совсем удачно.

Comment: зачем писать аж 3 `str_replace`, когда он может принимать аргументы массивы, непонятно.

Answer (score 1):

Ну ещё можно разбить строку на массив предложений по регулярке, а потом взять первые пять элементов массива:

```
$str = 'Cicero famously orated against his! Political opponent Lucius Sergius Catilina. Погода сегодня хорошая!

Occasionally the first Oration against Catiline is taken for type specimens: quo usque tandem abutere, Catilina, patientia nostra? Quam diu etiam furor iste tuus nos eludet? Cicero writing letters. Or maybe not.';

$offers = array_slice(preg_split('~(?<=[.!?])\s*(?=[A-ZА-ЯЁ])~', $str), 0, 5);

var_dump($offers);
```

Результат работы скрипта:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string 'Cicero famously orated against his!' (length=35)
  1 => string 'Political opponent Lucius Sergius Catilina.' (length=43)
  2 => string 'Погода сегодня хорошая!' (length=43)
  3 => string 'Occasionally the first Oration against Catiline is taken for type specimens: quo usque tandem abutere, Catilina, patientia nostra?' (length=130)
  4 => string 'Quam diu etiam furor iste tuus nos eludet?' (length=42)
```

Если нужно соединить эти пять предложений снова в строку, то воспользуйтесь подходящей php-функцией:

```
echo join(' ', $offers);
```

Comment: Откажитесь от JOIN в сторону IMPLODE

Comment: @Manitikyl ни-за-что! )